# Kakfa connector with helidon

Tags: apache-kafka, helidon

I am using helidon-kafka connector to connect to OCI streams through Helidon based app.
I have 2 topics and need different (de)serializers for both topics. I cannot add multiple connectors, adding 2 connectors by renaming them does not work. It generates following error

```
Exception in thread "main" io.helidon.microprofile.messaging.MessagingDeploymentException: No connector helidon-kaflka-2 found!
     at io.helidon.microprofile.messaging.ExceptionUtils.createNoConnectorFound(ExceptionUtils.java:30)
     at io.helidon.microprofile.messaging.UniversalChannel.lambda$findConnectors$0(UniversalChannel.java:170)
     at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
     at io.helidon.microprofile.messaging.UniversalChannel.findConnectors(UniversalChannel.java:170)
     at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
     at io.helidon.microprofile.messaging.ChannelRouter.connect(ChannelRouter.java:90)
```

Here is how I configuring it

```
outgoing.status-notifier:
  connector: helidon-kaka-2
  topic: ${STATUS_STREAM:-}

connector:
  helidon-kafka-2:
    bootstrap.servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
    ## Uncomment line 45, 46 and comment out 47, 48 for local dev env. ##
    sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
    sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<user_name>" password="<password>";
    #sasl.mechanism: OCI-RSA-SHA256
    #sasl.jaas.config: com.oracle.bmc.auth.sasl.InstancePrincipalsLoginModule required intent="streamPoolId:${STREAM_POOL_ID}";
    security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value.serializer: <package>.StatusChangeEventSerializer
    key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value.deserializer: <package>.StatusChangeEventDeserializer
```

How can I have different (de)serializer for both topics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the connector name "helidon-kaka-2". Change it to ["helidon-kaka" to match the documentation](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/reactivemessaging/04_kafka) and it should just work, provided everything else is fine with the rest of the configuration.

Why does this matter you ask? Refer to the relevant [connector code in Helidon](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/1cccbfc227ce39a385cee9aa81913c02e56867d2/messaging/connectors/kafka/src/main/java/io/helidon/messaging/connectors/kafka/KafkaConnector.java#L157) git, and you will realize the connectors identify themselves by fixed name and this is defined as

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Connector(KafkaConnector.CONNECTOR_NAME)
public class KafkaConnector ....

    /**
     * Microprofile messaging Kafka connector name.
     */
    static final String CONNECTOR_NAME = "helidon-kafka";
```

Answer (score 1):

We can have (de)serializers per channel. eg

```
outgoing.status_notifier_to_ai:
  connector: helidon-kafka
  topic: ${STATUS_STREAM:-}
  # default ser/deser apply here
  
outgoing.status_notifier_to_ai_2:
  connector: helidon-kafka
  topic: ${STATUS_STREAM:-}
  # Override config with custom per channel ser/deser config
  key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  value.serializer: <package>.DifferentStatusChangeEventSerializer
  key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value.deserializer: <package>.DifferentStatusChangeEventDeserializer

connector:
  helidon-kafka:
    bootstrap.servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
    ## Uncomment line 45, 46 and comment out 47, 48 for local dev env. ##
    sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
    sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<user_name>" password="<password>";
    #sasl.mechanism: OCI-RSA-SHA256
    #sasl.jaas.config: com.oracle.bmc.auth.sasl.InstancePrincipalsLoginModule required intent="streamPoolId:${STREAM_POOL_ID}";
    security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    # This is default for all the channels using this connector unless overriden
    key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value.serializer: <package>.StatusChangeEventSerializer
    key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value.deserializer: <package>.StatusChangeEventDeserializer
```